# How to create attribute from Intelligent cubes

Tags: attributes, microstrategy

We have Intelligent Cubes in my Microstrategy project.  I would like to create attribute  from Developer. I have connected to my project source and right clicked on  Schema objects -> Attributes . I don't see any Create Attribute button.I tried to create filter/Metric/Prompt for every thing its expecting attribute in Public objects->Attributes folder. How can I add a new attribute in the folder to create filter/Metric/Prompt

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this document. there are many ways to create attribute. hope its helping

https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/10.4/ProjectDesignGuide/WebHelp/Lang_1033/Content/ProjectDesign/Creating_attributes.htm